# Ошибка при подключении к бд в visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2012

Здравствуйте! Создаю проект в VS 2017 на c# для сдачи курсовой работы. В проекте фигурирует SQL Server база данных, созданная в данной версии VS. Но в учебном заведении стоят более ранние версии visual studio (2012). При попытке открыть свою БД вылетает ошибка несовместимости версий. А если попытаться открыть БД 2012 года в новой версии, то vs требует ее обновления.

**Вопрос:** можно ли настроить VS 2017 таким образом, чтобы он открывал БД ранних версий без их изменения? Или же проще будет установить Visual Studio 2012 года?

Comment: И какие пути решения предложили бы Вы?

Comment: Поясните, что значит "попытка открыть БД"  ?

Comment: Открыть содержимое таблиц в базе данных.

Comment: текст ошибки покажите